# How can I debug a bootloader and application in the same GDB session on Cortex-M devices?

Tags: gdb, embedded, remote-debugging, bootloader, cortex-m

Classic setup: There is a bootloader, and application, compiled separately. If everything is right, the bootloader jumps on the application.

I attach a probe, run the gdbserver, start gdb with the bootloader binary. If I run `file application.elf` then I lose my symbols for the bootloader.

How can I observe the handover, and what the application does exactly right after the jump, by running one instruction at a time?

Probably possible with an SWD commander by tracing the PC step-by-step and using addr2line to decode each step, but I'm hoping for a more proper way.

Comment: Typically the actual handoff is concise enough to debug using the symbols for one side and a general sense / objdump listing of the other in a window next to it.  Also note that on many of these devices, the recommended way to enter an application after a bootloader that has made non-trivial use of chip resources is to set a flag, reset the processor, notice the flag very early in startup and branch to the main application before doing any chip configuration.

Comment: Unless the problem is in the bootloader, typically setting a breakpoint on the entry point of the main firmware will work, and if the problem is in the bootloader, you can debug with its symbols and manually see that the entry point of the main firmware is read out of its vector table and branched to.  The things that tend to really need complex debugging are the peripheral state legacies of trying to avoid a CPU reset, which is why doing the reset is what *chip manufacturers* typically recommend.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisStratton, very insightful approach, I will keep this under consideration as I move forward with the product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the symbols with:

```
gdb add-symbol-file
```

Comment: This may have issues in practice given that there are likely to be duplicates of traditional symbol names between the independently compiled bootloader and main firmware projects, some originating in compiler libraries as well as those in user code and vendor hals which might be more readily reached by a batch rename.   But it's possible you might get enough uniqueness to figure things out.  Or perhaps one could figure out how to reprocess an elf prefixing all the symbols - the hardware of course only cares about the unique addresses.

Comment: As it is involved only a bootloader, one could just unload previous symbols, and add the new after the jump has been made. Just place a brackpoint on the jump between the two, and switch manually.

Comment: Sure, but swapping out one complete set of symbols for another is what the asker already knew how to do with the file command.  Adding an additional symbol file does seem like a useful trick in general though.